# Icon change works when debug, doesnt works when exe launched directly

Tags: c#, icons

I got little timer applicaton and i need to display current minute in its icon. So i draw couple of icons, put them into resources file.
Code for changing icon

```
   int currentMinute = Int32.Parse(label1.Text[0].ToString());
        if (currentMinute != globals.currentIcon)
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("PoE7MinTimerLolz.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            this.Icon = (Icon)rm.GetObject("_" + currentMinute);
            globals.currentIcon = currentMinute;
        }
```

Works perfectly when i debug application

[image: icon change]

But when i launch it from compiled exe file, icon doesn't changes from default

[image: default icon]

What do i do wrong?